# Can't install Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have an Asus X552EA-SX006D which I've upgraded(clean installed with) to Windows 10. The first time I tried to install ubuntu on the system, a GRUB installation error occurred, probably due Fastboot(I couldn't Secureboot option in my BIOS or anywhere). On the second attempt, everything went well and the installation succeeded, system restarted. But it did not reboot into ubuntu, there was no GRUB on startup and no ubuntu bootloader in boot menu. I intended to apply some repairs using LiveUSB, but I couldn't log into my installation, it rather entered into a fresh Try Ubuntu session. Also my system just won't boot Ubuntu LiveUSB in UEFI mode. So the BootRepair doesn't work either. I can't figure out any fix, inability to log into the system also prevents any repairs.

Comment: You say that the system, efi, and disk partitions can be identified with gparted, can you elaborate on that? I have been trying and can't figure out how :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you've been unable to boot the installer in EFI mode. This means that your installation must have been in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, which in turn means that you almost certainly have a mixed-mode (BIOS/EFI) installation (Linux in BIOS mode, Windows in EFI mode). This is a recipe for hair loss.

Ultimately, your best bet is to get the Ubuntu installer booting in EFI mode. If it won't boot at all -- that is, if you don't even see GRUB appear -- then chances are your USB drive was prepared with a tool that doesn't know how to create an EFI-bootable disk. Try another tool. Most people find that [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) works well from Windows, although there are other options. Once you get this working, you can either re-install or run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from the Ubuntu installer in its "try before installing" mode.

Alternatively, you could try installing my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) from Windows. You'll also need to install an EFI filesystem driver for whatever filesystem holds your kernel (ext4fs by default). This will be difficult to do if Secure Boot is active, though, since there's no setup script for Windows and the Secure Boot installation procedure is more complex. If you can do this, though, rEFInd will become your boot manager, bypassing GRUB.

Comment: Used Rufus 2.5 to create an EFI bootable media for GPT partition table. Worked without any problems. Thank You.